# Reactjs - How can I create a Boolean based off a successful axios POST?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a dispatch that I use to confirm if a user has logged-in. Right now, it currently sends data based off any input in the Login fields. Meaning, you can type in your wrong username and password and the dispatch will act as everything as if the credentials are right.

I would like to only use my dispatch once the user has successfully entered the correct username and password. Here is my code!

```
export default function SignIn() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        updateFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
        });
    };

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);

        axiosInstance
            .post(`auth/token/`, {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: formData.email,
                password: formData.password,

            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                history.push('/');
                window.location.reload();
            });

        dispatch(login({
            name: formData.email,
            password: formData.password,
            loggedIn: true,
        }))
    };
```

Below is the highlight of the problem, I would like to fire-off my dispatch ONLY if a user has successfully logged in. Currently, any textfield input will set off the dispatch.

```
        dispatch(login({
            name: formData.email,
            password: formData.password,
            loggedIn: true,
```

I was thinking a Boolean that provides a true false for successful POST HTTP 200 request? If there is a an easier way, then I would like to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your dispatch in the then block and add a catch method to handle errors

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
        .post(`auth/token/`, {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: formData.email,
            password: formData.password,

        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
            history.push('/');
            window.location.reload();
            dispatch(login({
             name: formData.email,
             password: formData.password,
             loggedIn: true,
           }))
        })
        .catch(err => {
           // HANDLE ERROR HERE
        }
};
```

Comment: I have one more question, what would you recommend I add in the error function?

Comment: You would ideally be receiving a 400 status code from the server. Depending on how it is configured, you may be getting an error message. So you could display that error message to the user. i.e. "email doesn't exist", "password incorrect"